# How to select rows which are today events?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a set of tables (phonebooks, numbers, extrafields, extradatas)

- phonebooks - List of users phonebooks (`username`, `book_id`, `title`)
- numbers - List of each phonebook numbers (`number_id`, `book_id`, `number`, `fullname`)
- extrafields - List of extra fields (birthday, email, ...) and its table fields are : `field_id`, `title`
- extradatas - List of extra data of each number's extra fileds (`book_id`, `field_id`, `number_id`, `value`)
- relations -  Which extra-field belongs to which phonebook (`book_id`, `field_id`)

Imagine a user who have a phonebook and an extra field of birthday.
How can i select numbers which their birthday is today?

**EDIT:** I have specified `uname`, `book_id`, `field_id` in my hands (from PHP script) and results must be limited to these values.

Note that i save date fields in unix timestamp and `extradatas`.`value` type is varchar.
This is the **hardest** math-join-select in my life (i think).

Why math? : because i want to calculate day number from unix timestamp, without need to use functions (like DATE_FORMAT)

Comment: Why do you use unix timestamp to store date of birth?

Comment: because i think its more quick to work on unix timestamps than formatted date strings. am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.number
FROM phonebooks p
INNER JOIN  numbers n ON n.book_id = p.book_id
INNER JOIN extradatas ed ON ed.book_id = n.book_id
INNER JOIN extrafields ef ON ef.field_id = ed.field_id AND ef.title = 'birthday'
WHERE p.book_id = :book_id
    AND p.username = :username
    AND ed.value BETWEEN unix_timestamp(DATE(now()))
        AND unix_timestamp(DATE(now()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Note that the only significant difference (that I see) between my answer and @Andrej L's is how I compare dates. On larger datasets, @Andrej L's solution would require converting every birthday in the system using DATEFORMAT. My solution should allow MySQL to evaluate the comparisons once, up front, and possibly take advantage of an index for extrafields.value.

Comment: Why `ef.value`? Shouldn't it be `ed.value` ? Besides i have specified `book_id` , `field_id`, `uname` in my hand (from PHP script) and results must limit to these conditions.

Comment: Yes, it should be ed.value. I'll also update the query to account for the additional conditions...

Comment: Thank you Doug for your effort on my questions.

Comment: I think that update should do it. I didn't add field_id, but I was unclear as to how you wanted to use it. If you had field_id for the field where `title = 'birthday'`, then you could remove the `extrafields` join, and specify the field_id directly.

Comment: Yes i have field_id. And is there a way to calculate day number from unix timestamp without need to use DATE or DATE_FORMAT ? And of course if that's faster than DATE function.

Comment: The important function of `DATE()` above is to remove the time element from `now()` - you want `'2011-08-20'`, not `'2011-08-20 13:26:33'`. The `unix_timestamp()` and `from_unixtime()` functions convert your dates back and forth.

Comment: I think your query is a little wrong. What would happen if a row's birthday (ed.value) = 1975/02/15 ? I want this row be present in result if today is 2011/ **02/15**.

Comment: @DougKress let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2699/discussion-between-aram-alipoor-and-doug-kress)

Answer (score 0):

Try torun:

```
Select number from numbers as n inner join extradatas e on (n.number_id=e.number_id and  n.book_id=e.book_id) inner join extrafields ex on e.field_id=ex.field_id
where ex.title='birthday' and DATE_FORMAT(ex.value, '%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```